# Введение чего-либо в input() во время "сна" программы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Была проблема в некоторых программах, которые требовали что-либо запомнить, а потом это ввести. Но при ожидании - `time.sleep()`, если там что-либо ввести (даже нажать "Enter"), оно появится в строке введения значений после ожидания. Я хочу это исправить чтобы такой ситуации не было, просим помощи! Предоставляю к примеру образец кода:

```
import time

time.sleep(3) # Проблема

input_total = input()
```

Comment: Читайте про потоки.

Comment: Благодарю, Сергей!